# Output to both console and txt file

Tags: c, unix

I think this is written in C, honestly don't know how to identify (if someone could give some tips it would be great). When the command **rpt dumpvars 1234** is run in the console it returns the variables of machine/node 1234 to the screen. I want the same data output to a variables.txt file. Is there a simple one liner that I can add to do this?

The file is [located here](https://github.com/ismaelisuani/rpt_events/blob/master/app_rpt.c).

The portion of the data I am trying to get can be found on lines 7590-7623 as pasted here:

```
/*
* Display a node's main channel variables from the command line 
*/
static int rpt_do_showvars(int fd, int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i,thisRpt = -1;
struct ast_var_t *newvariable;

if (argc != 3) return RESULT_SHOWUSAGE;
for(i = 0; i < nrpts; i++)
{
    if(!strcmp(argv[2], rpt_vars[i].name))
    {
        thisRpt = i;
        break;
    } 
} 

if (thisRpt < 0)
{
    ast_cli(fd, "Unknown node number %s.\n", argv[2]);
    return RESULT_FAILURE;
} 
i = 0;
ast_cli(fd,"Variable listing for node %s:\n",argv[2]);
ast_channel_lock(rpt_vars[thisRpt].rxchannel);
AST_LIST_TRAVERSE (&rpt_vars[thisRpt].rxchannel->varshead, newvariable, 
entries) {
    i++;
    ast_cli(fd,"   %s=%s\n", ast_var_name(newvariable), 
ast_var_value(newvariable));
}
ast_channel_unlock(rpt_vars[thisRpt].rxchannel);
ast_cli(fd,"    -- %d variables\n", i);
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Does it work the same in this script as I have used it in Bash? Sorry for the question, bash is my level - not this stuff. I am way out of my comfort zone on this. Where within all those curly brackets would I put the tee command to not get an error?

Comment: The file you linked to is that of an [asterisk](https://www.asterisk.org/) module. Modifying the C code to write to a file would be non-trivial. You can just call `asterisk -rx "rpt dumpvars 1234" > variables.txt` from the command line.

Comment: THANK YOU SEAN! The -rx part of the string is what I couldn't remember. I used to use that all the time, it's been so long. That will be so much better than modifying this file.

Comment: If you can't remember the flag to be used with the command, you can save some time and look it up in the man. Most likely there is a `man asterisk` page for your needs, or just look it up on the internet :)